# Bubble sort, can't enter for loop

Tags: c++

I am making a bubble sort program using vectors and I am unable to enter the for loop in BubbleSort that is supposed to display my result after sorting.
I am sorting a vector and I want to sort it by Departure (it is declared in another file).

I am expecting a sorted list of Flights, sorted by departure time that is a string.

Here is my code:

```
Header:
class BubbleSort : public Sort
{
public:
    // main entry point
    void sort(std::vector<Flight>& data);
};

void BubbleSort::sort(std::vector<Flight>& data)
{
    list<Flight>::iterator m = flights.begin();
    int temp;
    while (m != flights.end()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <data.size(); ++i) 
            for(int j = 0; j < (data.size()-1); ++j)
                if (data[j] > data[j+1]) {
                    Flight temp = data[j];
                    data[j] = data[j+1];
                    data[j+1] = temp;
                }
        for(int k = 0; k < data.size(); ++k) {       //the problematic loop
            cout << "Array after bubble sort: ";
            cout << data[k].getDeparture() << endl;
        }
        m++;
    }
}

main: 
// global variables
vector<Flight> flightsVector;           //vector containing all flights
list<Flight> flights;                   //list containing flights (objects of class Flight)
list<string> flightDepartures;

// function declarations
void loadFlights(ifstream& in);

void fillFlightsList();                 //fills flights with flights objects (formed of destinations, departures, flight numbers and gate numbers)
void printFlightsList();                //prints the list of flights

void display_info();
void printFlightsList();


void main()
{
    vector<Flight> data;
    ifstream in("inputFileExample.txt");
    if (!in)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: wrong input file name!";
        exit(-1);
    }

//  Sort* s;

    loadFlights(in);
    fillFlightsList();

    printFlightsList();
    cout << endl;

    BubbleSort bubble;
    bubble.sort(data);
    cout << endl;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see what data vector contains after your bubble sort?

Comment: Your description is lacking a description of what you expect and what you observe. Voting to close until it's improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the list is empty.